# How to make container visible only to other containers within the same network

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-network

I just started to learn the docker and try to adapt it for my need.
Given such simple docker-compose file

```
version: '3'

services:

    my-client:
        container_name: my-client
        build:
            context: ./client
            dockerfile: Dockerfile_dev
        ports:
            - "3000:3000"
        volumes:
            - ./client/src:/srv/dev/client/src
            - ./client/public:/srv/dev/client/public
        command: npm run start

    my-nginx:
        container_name: my-nginx
        build: ./nginx
        links:
            - my-client
        expose:
            - 80
        ports:
            - "80:80"
```

(nginx just proxies requests to the client)

Currently I can access my client through `localhost`, and through `localhost:3000`, which is not good. I want just 1 port to be visible outside of my network, and all other containers to be hidden. Is that possible to setup network in a way when `outside->nginx->client`, but not `outside->client`

Comment: Not sure why someone marked this question as not useful. The OP asked a very valid question as a beginner in my opinion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just drop this:

```
ports:
            - "3000:3000"
```

Then the only way to access this container is outside -> nginx -> client (or `localhost`, if you try from the machine where the containers run). Nginx will still be able to reach the container at port 3000, but others won't.

Comment: thank you, that works. Strange, I seems tried that before. Anyway I got what I wanted!